# How to get uncompressed BTC address and private key from bit module for Python?

Tags: private-key, python

I am new in programming and BTC. I want to make some BTC address with private keys. Till now I learn that we have compressed and uncompressed private keys. But I get only compressed private keys and address. How I can get uncompressed private key and adress with bit module? This number is just for example. I don't use them for my address. Please do the same. It's not safe to use it for your address. I made this code till now

```
from bit import Key
dec=115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518156494336
key = Key.from_int(dec)
print(key.address)
print(key.to_wif())
```

I get this results 1A7o1vWzF4fx1yqmA1NzFbhnP97P9uYQ2Q L5oLkpV3aqBjhki6LmvChTCV6odsp4SXM6FfU2GppfKbjNXRE2Ge

I use this module https://pypi.org/project/bit/

If you know someone who can help please share with me. You can see code here https://pastebin.com/6gk1Ua2b

Comment: Why would you want to use uncompressed points?

Comment: maybe this will help? https://github.com/ofek/bit/issues/52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like doing such a conversion is not well supported, nor is instantiating a private key as uncompressed unless you do so with a WIF key.

However, you can change the compressed-ness by doing:

```
key._public_key = key._pk.public_key.format(compressed=False)
```

But this requires you do to this immediately after instantiation as otherwise precomputed properties such as `.address` will not be recomputed.

Comment: Note that there generally is no reason you'd want to use uncompressed public keys.